# I happen to stumble upon this code :" With for w in words:, the example would attempt to create an infinite list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, infinite

I couldn't find an explanation for the code in [python doc article 4.2](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) regarding the for loop.

It mentioned something like: if we don't make a copy of the list, then it will print infinite list values for the list `words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']`; but not if we make a copy of it beforehand using `"for w in words[:]"`. I need an explanation for this.

```
words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
for w in words :
    if len(w) > 6:
       words.insert(0,w)
```

This code will run in an infinite loop, but not if we swap the `for w in`words`with`for w in words[:]`

Comment: `words[:]` creates a copy of the list `words` so you are iterating over a copy but inserting to the original list.

Answer (score 1):

With `[:]` you create a copy of the list content at that moment, and that would be:

```
words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']  # equals words[:]

for i, w in enumerate(words[:]):
    print(i, w)
    if len(w) > 6:
        words.insert(0,w)
        print("len:", len(words))

#0 cat
#1 window
#2 defenestrate
#len: 4
```

But using the `words` variable itself, stepping your loop does nothing as your step forward is annulled with the insertion at the first position:

```
words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']

for i, w in enumerate(words):
    print(i, w)
    if len(w) > 6:
        words.insert(0,w)
        print("len:", len(words))

#0 cat
#1 window
#2 defenestrate
#len: 4
#3 defenestrate
#len: 5
#4 defenestrate
#len: 6
#5 defenestrate
#len: 7
#6 defenestrate
#len: 8
#7 defenestrate
#len: 9
#...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [:] function in python creates a copy of a list. Let's take the following code as an example:

First, create a list: `words`

```
words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
```

Create two new variables base on words:

```
words_copy = words[:] # this is a copy
words_ref = words # this is reference
```

The values are still equal:

```
assert words == words_copy
assert words == words_ref
```

but the menory lolcation isn't:

```
assert id(words) != id(words_copy)
assert id(words) == id(words_ref)
```

Next we'll modify the list (like you do in the loop):

```
words.append('foo')
```

Now the values aren't equal for the copy, but remain equal for the reference:

```
assert words != words_copy
assert words == words_ref
assert id(words) != id(words_copy)
assert id(words) == id(words_ref)
```

So by taking a copy of the array and using that in the loop, you're not modifying the object inside of the loop.

Simples!